# How to remove single quotes from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to output an object array from an existing array I have, however, the existing array doesn't have keys so in an attempt to create it I did this

```
  ...
  var range = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i ++ ) {
      range.push('{ date: "'+dateArray[i]+'" }')
  }
  var fake = "'"+myArray+"'"
  var p = fake.replace(/[']+/g, '')
  var o = [p]
```

console logging my "o" variable gives me this....

```
[ '{ date: "Wed Jun 08 2016 12:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)" },{ date: "Thu Jun 09 2016 12:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)" }...']
```

The problem is that my objects within the array get's wrapped by single quotes, causing it to be recognized as one big string.

Seeing how this is no longer recognized as a string, I cannot do str.replace to get rid of the unwanted quotes. Ultimately I want it to look like this:

```
[ { date: "Wed Jun 08 2016 12:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)" },{ date: "Thu Jun 09 2016 12:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)" }...]
```

Comment: use JSON.parse() documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse

Comment: `JSON.parse()` is useless in the given example.  In fact, it throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
  var range = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i ++ ) {
      range.push({ date: dateArray[i].toString() })
  }
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I guess I was just doing too much. I'm probably going to use it without the toString function like in the post after this, but it doesn't seem fair to  accept that one because it's the exact same fix as yours, aside from that. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You only have to remove the single quotation mark when add it to the array. You must add to the array an object and not a string.

```
var range = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i ++ ) {
      range.push({ date: dateArray[i] })
  }
```

Comment: apology would look like this var range = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i ++ ) {
      range.push({ date: dateArray[i] })
  }

Comment: You can edit your anwser if you want to add changes... :)

Comment: Cool thanks. Now, based on that OP "misused" my answer, it's not what he's looking for. :(

Comment: Your answer has blatant errors. `JSON.stringify(i)` passes an integer to JSON.stringify.  Please clean it up or delete it.